# Hibernate Many-to-Many with join is taking time to fetch all data

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have bidirectional many-to-one association

```
    <class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="addresses" 
        table="PersonAddress">
        <key column="personId"/>
        <many-to-many column="addressId"
            unique="true"
            class="Address"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <join table="PersonAddress" 
        inverse="true" 
        optional="true">
        <key column="addressId"/>
        <many-to-one name="person"
            column="personId"
            not-null="true"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

when I run below hql query in my application for getting all data from Person table left join with PersonAddress and Address but it will take more than 2 min to load the data while all data is 5k, Please help me on how can i reduce the time?

```
session.createQuery("from Person b ");
```

Below is the table structure

```
create table Person ( personId bigint not null primary key )
create table PersonAddress ( personId bigint not null, addressId bigint not null)
create table Address ( addressId bigint not null primary key )
```

Comment: Can you log the generated SQL and execute directly to the database? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: After generated the sql it will take only .4 -.5 sec in SQL Developer